# How to add a span just before an existing span tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to add a span tag in HTML form just before another existing span tag using javascript? I know the id of existing span tag.

Comment: It would be very kind of you if you showed us your current effort in your question instead of the one liner..

Comment: You know you haven't done enough research when you get 8 answers within 10 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

JS

```
 $(function(){
  var addNewSpan = '<span class="PQM">New Span</span>';
  $('#xyz').click(function(){
   $('#abc').before(addNewSpan);
  });
});
```

HTML

```
 <span id="abc"> Hello</span>
 <input type="button" id="xyz" value="ABC"/>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KdEFG/1/)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var addnew = '<span class="newcssclass">new content</div>';


 $('.classofthespantoclick').click(function(){

 $('#existingspanid').before(addnew);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the `before()` method, something like:

```
$("#mySpan").before("<span>My new span</span>");
```

[before() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)
and 
[jQuery Before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)
is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) function of jQuery.

Something like this:

```
theThingYouWantToAdd.insertBefore($('#idOfOtherEl'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following:**

```
var value = document.createElement("span");
value.innerHTML = "Some text";
document.body.insertBefore(value, spanID);
```

*Hope this helps :)*

Answer (score 0):

In YUI we can do it like:

```
var newSpan = Y.Node.create("<span>");

Y.one("#myspan").insertBefore(newSpan);
```